# Py class inheritance doesn't work (no errors show up)

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I'm creating a class Player(Turtle) << to inherit the turtle class

```
from turtle import Turtle
STARTING_POSITION = (0, -280)
MOVE_DISTANCE = 10
FINISH_LINE_Y = 280


# noinspection PyInterpreter

class Player(Turtle):

    def __int__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape("turtle")
        self.color("black")
        self.penup()
        self.goto(STARTING_POSITION)
        self.setheading(90)
```

Then I create new player = Player() in main.py

```
import time
from turtle import Screen
from player import Player

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.tracer(0)

player = Player()

game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    screen.update()
```

No errors are given, but neither class attributes work. I get, arrow in center of screen. I'm stuck can't find answer by googling

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "neither class attributes work"? What do you expect this program to do?

Comment: I really feel like you meant to type `__init__` not `__int__` in your player class

Comment: oh lord, how couldn't I notice that. Sorry for wasting your time! 

Thanks a lot Luke!